# Scheduling a publish to Google Play Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I have an application published to the Google Play store (version 1) and I have planned to update it soon to version 2.
I have already uploaded the updated APK, but I don't want to publish the new version to the store until the 1st of January at midnight (The content in the updated app is all specific to 2013.)
I'd rather not have to log in at midnight on new year's day to do the publish manually. Is there some sort of functionality to allow me to schedule an automated publish to the Google Play store on that date and time?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality available on Google Play.

Comment: Would be useful though.

Answer (score 3):

Now there is a possibility of **Timed publishing**:

> Updates to existing apps are processed as usual, but you control the
>   specific moment your update goes live.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282

Comment: Still not usefull, we wanted to publish on a non-labor day but you cannot schedule to publish automatically on a later date.